# Could the polynomial $f(t,c)=\sum_{i=1}^{c} (2i-1)t^{i-1}$ be written as a rational function in $t$ and $q=t^c$?

Tags: calculus, combinatorics

Could the polynomial $f(t,c)=\sum_{i=1}^{c} (2i-1)t^{i-1}$ be written as a rational function in $t$ and $q=t^c$ of the form $\frac{g(t,q)}{h(t,q)}$, where $g(t,q)$, $h(t,q)$ are polynomials in $t,q$ and the coefficients of $g, h$ do not involve $c$? I think that this is impossible. But I want to make sure. Thank you very much.

Edit: 
\begin{align}
(1-t)f(t,c) & = 1+\sum_{i=1}^{c-1}2t^i-(2c-1)t^c \\
& = \frac{1+t-q-2cq}{1-t}.
\end{align}

Therefore $f(t,c) = \frac{1+t-q-2cq}{(1-t)^2}$. The coefficient of $q$ involves $c$. Therefore I think that it is impossible to write $f(t,c)$ as a rational function of $t, q$ whose coefficients do not involve $c$. Is this correct? Thank you very much.

Comment: Why do you think it's impossible?

Comment: Hint: $(1-t)f(t,c)$ is almost a finite geometric series.